# how to install the sims 3 in playonlinux on Ubuntu 64bit?

Tags: wine, 64-bit, games, playonlinux

I've been trying to install the game the *sims 3* for days now using guides I found via google but I can't manage to make it work.

My system details:

> Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-3317U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4
>   Graphics: Intel® Ivybridge Mobile
>   Memory: 3.8 GiB
>   OS: 64-bit

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, wine 1.7.27, and playonlinux 4.2.5, and the original DVD of the base game

The guide I used to try to install the game is [this one](http://www.maketecheasier.com/play-the-sims3-in-linux) (it's a bit old).

At the end of the installation a few wine windows popped up saying there had been an error (without specifying what error).

Now on POL there are two items one is the Sims 2 and the other is the Sims 3 Launcher. If try to open the first nothing happens, if I try the second one it says:

```
a fatal error occurred. however, `mscorees.dll` could not be loaded to display the appropriate error message. please reinstall the .NET framework.
```

Could you help me figure out what to do to make the game work? Please explain step by step if possible.

Let me know if more information is needed.

----EDIT

it's not a duplicate of that question, i have already tried the suggestions i found in the answers to that question.
i think that my problem with the installation is caused by the fact i have 64-bit ubuntu and wine.

----EDIT 2

marking my question as a duplicate even after i specified the problem i have is different from that question is very unhelpful.